# Second null character is ignored in string

Tags: c, arrays, string, null, initialization

I am initializing a string(array of characters) in C and i noticed that even if i enter a second null character(\0) in the string it is ignored and does not return any error. See below what i mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char word[]= {'H','e','l','l','o','\0','\0'};
    char word2[]= "Hello\0\0";
    printf("Word  is : %s\n",word);     // Prints "Hello"
    printf("Word  2 is : %s\n",word2);  // Prints "Hello" as well

     return 0;
}
```

Can you please explain why?

Comment: The second case `word2[]` actually has *three* nul characters: the two you placed there, and the one the compiler placed there.

Comment: What is the reason for down votes?

Comment: Probably because you don't show any research effort? How about reading a C book before asking, that is basic stuff.

Answer (score 4):

In C, a "string" as a defined as a sequence of non-nul characters terminated by a nul. So the second nul is not part of the string. The first nul marks the end -- that's how `printf` knows how many characters to print when you use the `%s` format specifier.

Comment: Although it's part of the array and that's perfectly Ok.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi So, it is part of the array but not part of the string?

Comment: Correct. Consider `char j[100];` then later `strcpy(j, "hi");`. Here, `j` is 100 bytes of stuff in an array. It also contains the string "hi" which is two characters and a terminating nul. The large array serves as the container to hold the smaller string (and a bunch of other stuff).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you expected.

Any array of characters that ends with a `'\0'` is a string. What comes after the end of the string doesn't matter, since the string has ended.

This is fine too:

```
const char *two = "hello\0there";

printf("%s\n", two);
```

This prints

```
hello
```

The characters after the embedded `'\0'` don't matter, they're not part of the string that starts at `two` so of course `printf()` doesn't care.

You can treat the remaining characters as a string too, of course:

```
printf("%s\n", two + 6);
```

This would print

```
there
```

Since the second half is also a valid string (double-quoted literals like this add the terminator). So in a way `two` contains two strings, which is my point.

Answer (score 2):

The NUL character (or null character if you are reading the C standard) terminates a C string. It's an indicator so you won't need to lug the size of the string around. And there is nothing that precludes other values from being placed after it in the buffer, including other NUL characters. In fact the C standard library even has the destructive `strtok` function that places this character inside strings as part of "tokenization".

Comment: @TonyTannous And we are thankful because you're wrong.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi ok I'd love for an explanation :)

Comment: @TonyTannous - NULL is constant, NUL is a common abbreviation we'd use to avoid confusion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: @StoryTeller true...
I am a bit off this morning :) sorry.

Comment: Why don't you use the expression 'null character', which is used by the C Standard.

Comment: @2501 - Old habits. It's the lingo at my work place, I'll add a footnote

Comment: @StoryTeller I will have the strtok function in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most string operations in C (such as `printf`) know when to stop reading a string once it finds a NULL terminator. It stops searching at that point.

In fact, `printf` is not designed to print the NULL terminator. All strings in C are meant to end with one, so if they were printed, every string would have a '\0' in output as well. That would be very pointless.

Answer (score 1):

> Second null character is ignored in string

No, it is not ignored. If you run this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char word[]= {'H','e','l','l','o','\0','\0'};
    char word2[]= "Hello\0\0";

    printf( "sizeof( word ) = %zu\n", sizeof( word ) );
    printf( "sizeof( word2 ) = %zu\n", sizeof( word2 ) );
}
```

You will get the following result

```
sizeof( word ) = 7
sizeof( word2 ) = 8
```

That is all zero-characters were included in the character arrays.

Take into account that string literals contain also invisible null-terminating character. That is this string literal `"Hello\0\0"` (having type `char[8]`) is stored in memory like `{ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '\0', '\0' }`.

Redundant zero characters are ignored by some functions like for example the function `strlen` or the function `printf` when the format specifier `%s` is used because these functions consider character arrays as containing strings that is a sequence of characters delimited by a zero character.

Moreover you can initializer all elements of a character array with zeroes. For example

```
char s[5] = { '\0' };
```

This declaration is equivalent to

```
char s[5] = { '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0' };
```

Or you even can write

```
char s[] = "\0\0\0\0";
```

In fact this declaration is equivalent to the previous declaration of the array `s` that is the array will contain `5` zero characters.

If you execute this statement

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( s ) );
```

you will get as expected `5`. However if you execute this statement

```
printf( "%zu\n", strlen( s ) );
```

or this statement

```
printf( "%s\n", s );
```

you will get 0 or (in the second case) nothing will be displayed except the cursor will be moved on the next line..

Comment: Useful tips. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have 3 `'\0'`s in your second array. But note that the `'\0'` or ascii *nul* is considered the delimiter of strings in c, in fact as others have said in c, a string is nothing but a sequence of bytes followed by a `'\0'` byte.

So your assumption that something special should be done with "*extra*" `'\0'`s is wrong. In fact, I say "*extra*" because even though they are part of the array, they are not part of the string, and to be sure you can try

```
char string[] = "Example\0Example";
```

and you will see that the whole "*Example*" after the `'\0'` will not be printed if you use `printf()`, nor will it be taken into account by `strlen()` or any `str`* funcion. Furthermore, it has 2 `'\0'` in principle, the one explicitly inserted and another one that is implicitly added after the second "*Example*".

Comment: I am keeping the "ascii nul is considered the delimited of strings in C" and the "nor will it be taken into account by strlen() or any str* funcion". Useful tips. Thank you